# reading multiple text files from different folders python

Tags: python, regex, loops, text

So, I'm trying to look through multiple text files located in different folders:

```
path1 = 'P:/folder1/best_par.txt'
path2 = 'P:/folder2/best_par.txt'
paths = (path1, path2)
for i in paths:
    inputfile = open(i)
    text = inputfile.read()
    cn2 = re.findall(r'(CN2\.mgt)\s+([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', text)
```

However, as a result I have only one cn2 value from two files:

```
[('CN2.mgt', '0.142800')]
```

Should be smth like this:

```
[('CN2.mgt', '0.142800')],[('CN2.mgt', '0.09017')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
path1 = 'P:/folder1/best_par.txt'
path2 = 'P:/folder2/best_par.txt'
paths = (path1, path2)
for i in paths:
    inputfile = open(i)
    text = inputfile.read()
    cn2 = re.findall(r'(CN2\.mgt)\s+([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', text)
```

When your loop runs for first time path1 best_par is read and cn2 is found.

Now, when loop continues running, cn2 of second path is found and it overwrites the first cn2. So, only the second cn2 is left.

What you should do:-

```
path1 = 'P:/folder1/best_par.txt'
path2 = 'P:/folder2/best_par.txt'
paths = (path1, path2)
for i in paths:
    inputfile = open(i)
    text = inputfile.read()
    print re.findall(r'(CN2\.mgt)\s+([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', text)
```

or:-

```
cn2 = []
path1 = 'P:/folder1/best_par.txt'
path2 = 'P:/folder2/best_par.txt'
paths = (path1, path2)
for i in paths:
    inputfile = open(i)
    text = inputfile.read()
    cn2.append(re.findall(r'(CN2\.mgt)\s+([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', text))
for i in cn2:
    print i
```

Comment: Use the last is best

Comment: I think in the second option last two lines should be:
    for i in cn2:
    print i

Comment: @Shubham Sharma This is almost it. The first option with print works perfectly, but the second option with append gives me 10 values from which two are unique.
 '[('CN2.mgt', '0.142800'),
 ('CN2.mgt', '0.142800'),
 [('CN2.mgt', '0.081993'), ('CN2.mgt', '0.081993')],
 [('CN2.mgt', '0.142800'), ('CN2.mgt', '0.142800')],
 [('CN2.mgt', '0.081993'), ('CN2.mgt', '0.081993')],
 [('CN2.mgt', '0.142800'), ('CN2.mgt', '0.142800')]]'

Comment: you might be having cn2  = [] outside some other loop of your code

Comment: @Shubham Sharma I figured it out: I forgot cn2 = [] before the loop, not inside the loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your cn2 variable, you should declare it outside of the loop and append to it all the results.

Comment: Even if I declare the variable outside of the loop, I have only one value at the end.